# Test lambda functions in Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, lambda, kotlin, mockito

I need to Unit-Test a function `doClassAction` and inside it calls the function `doStoreAction` on the object `store`.
This `doStoreAction` accepts two parameters, one integer and one function, like in the example below

```
class MyStore() {

    fun doStoreAction(num: Int, callback: (text: String) -> Unit) {
        // It does something 
        // ...
        // and when it's done it calls the callback

        return callback("some text")
    }
}

class MyClass(private val store: MyStore,
              private val objectX: MyObject) {

    fun doClassAction(num: Int) {
        store.doStoreAction(num) { callbackResult ->
            // Action (potentially asynchronous)
            // that will happen after obtaining the value via the callback

            objectX.doObjectAction(callbackResult)
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `Mockito` and so far my test has the following lines

```
@Test
fun doClassActionTest() {
    val mockStore = mock(MyStore::class.java)
    val mockObject = mock(MyObject::class.java)
    val class = MyClass(mockStore, mockObject)
    class.doClassAction(42)
}
```

But it doesn't compile because the call to the method does not specify the callback... I don't want to overwrite it since I want the test to use the original one and verify that the things inside are called properly, like:

```
when(objectX.doObjectAction(anyString())).doNothing()
verify(objectX, times(1)).doObjectAction(callbackResult)
```

Is there a way to call the method and also mock the callback response to a value I set in the tests but still have it go through the original code flow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After days of trying out things and reading about it, I finally found a solution that works and I'll share it here for whomever find themselves in the same pickle

```
@Test
fun doClassActionTest() {
    val mockStore = mock(MyStore::class.java)
    val mockObject = mock(MyObject::class.java)
    val myClass = MyClass(mockStore, mockObject)
    val input = 42
    val resultCallback = "test result"

    `when`(mockStore.doStoreAction(any(), any())).then { invocation ->
        (invocation.arguments[1] as (String) -> Unit).invoke(resultCallback)
    }

    myClass.doClassAction(input)

    verify(mockObject, only()).doObjectAction(resultCallback)
}
```

The caveat here is to remember to put the classes that you are mocking AND the methods called by those classes as `open` in Kotlin otherwise there could be **false positives**

P.s. I also used few inline functions extracted from the [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) library such as:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> any() = Mockito.any(T::class.java) ?: createInstance<T>()

inline fun <reified T : Any> createInstance(): T = createInstance(T::class)

fun <T : Any> createInstance(kClass: KClass<T>): T = castNull()

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
private fun <T> castNull(): T = null as T
```

Comment: To handle the situation with the classes to be open in order to be able to test them you could use the Kotlin allopen plugin. Check it out here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html .

Comment: Instead of the ugly  \`when\` you can use `whenever()` extension from the same library.

Comment: been using this approach before found your answer: https://dev.to/ychescale9/testing-kotlin-lambda-invocations-without-mocking-3n32. Thanks for this approaches!